# MYSQL SELECT to DELETE specified twice

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a problem when I change SELECT to DELETE:

```
DELETE
FROM mitarbeiter
WHERE mitarbeiter.pers_nr=
(SELECT mitarbeiter.pers_nr
FROM mitarbeiter
LEFT JOIN kunde ON kunde.betreuer=mitarbeiter.pers_nr
group by mitarbeiter.pers_nr
order by count(*)
limit 1);
```

The error says...

`Table 'mitarbeiter' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data`

How can I change that?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to delete the resultset.
The task is to fire/delete the employee=mitarbeiter who has the lowest count of kunde=customers

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the logic with a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE m
    FROM mitarbeiter m JOIN
         (SELECT m2.pers_nr
          FROM mitarbeiter m2 LEFT JOIN
               kunde k
               ON k.betreuer = m2.pers_nr 
          GROUP BY m2.pers_nr 
          ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
          LIMIT 1
         ) m2
         ON m.pers_nr = m2.pers_nr;
```

That said, the logic can probably be simplified, but it is strange.  You are using `COUNT(*)` with a `LEFT JOIN`, so even non-matches in the second table get a count of 1.  Knowing your intentions -- with sample data and desired results -- would help others figure out if another approach would work better.

Comment: What d be ur suggestion? 
I'm totally new in SQL
The task was to fire the employee=mitarbeiter with the lowest count of customers=kunde

Answer (score 1):

Instead of where and subquery you could try usin a join based and a table as alias for the same subquery

```
DELETE m.*
FROM mitarbeiter m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT mitarbeiter.pers_nr
    FROM mitarbeiter
    LEFT JOIN kunde ON kunde.betreuer=mitarbeiter.pers_nr
    group by mitarbeiter.pers_nr
    order by count(*)
    limit 1
) t ON t.pers_nr = m.pers_nr
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround you could try is saving your subquery in a temporary table, then calling on rows from that table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable
SELECT mitarbeiter.pers_nr 
FROM mitarbeiter 
LEFT JOIN kunde 
ON kunde.betreuer=mitarbeiter.pers_nr 
GROUP BY mitarbeiter.pers_nr 
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
LIMIT 1;

DELETE FROM mitarbeiter 
WHERE mitarbeiter.pers_nr 
IN (
    SELECT * FROM tempTable
);

DROP TABLE tempTable;  -- cleanup
```

*Warning: this may take a much longer time and/or larger space than using JOIN as in the other solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this help point you in the right direction?

I often find that result visualization is easier for my feeble brain when I use [Common Table Expressions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

Please note that **MySQL prior to version 8.0 [doesn't support the WITH clause](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23156)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mitarbeiter (
  pers_nr varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (pers_nr)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO mitarbeiter (pers_nr) VALUES
('Scum'),
('Worker'),
('Manager'),
('President');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kunde (
  kunde_id int(3) NOT NULL,
  betreuer varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (kunde_id)  
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO kunde (kunde_id, betreuer) VALUES
(1, 'Scum'),
(2, 'Worker'),
(3, 'Worker'),
(4, 'Manager'),
(5, 'Manager'),
(6, 'Manager'),
(7, 'President'),
(8, 'President'),
(9, 'President'),
(10, 'President');

WITH s1
AS
(SELECT betreuer
      , count(1) AS kunde_count_by_pers_nr -- JJAUSSI: find the kunde count by pers_nr
  FROM kunde
 GROUP BY betreuer
  ),
s2
AS
(SELECT MIN(kunde_count_by_pers_nr) AS kunde_count_by_pers_nr_min -- JJAUSSI: find the lowest kunde_count
  FROM s1),
s3
AS
(SELECT s1.betreuer
  FROM s1 INNER JOIN s2
    ON s1.kunde_count_by_pers_nr = s2.kunde_count_by_pers_nr_min -- JJAUSSI: Retrieve all the betreuer values with the lowest kunde_count
)
SELECT * -- JJAUSSI: Test this result and see if it contains the records you expect to delete
  FROM s3;
--DELETE -- JJAUSSI: Once you are confident in the results from s3, this DELETE can work
--  FROM mitarbeiter
-- WHERE pers_nr IN (SELECT betreuer
--                   FROM s3);

SELECT * -- JJAUSSI: Check for the desired results (we successfully got rid of 'Scum'!)
  FROM mitarbeiter;
```